# Python selenium to extract elements with xpath and for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am using Python/Selenium to extract some text from a website to further sort it in Google Sheets.

There are 15 headers for which I need to extract text. The text is found under each header in tag h5.

Here's one extract of a header:

```
<tr class="dayHeader">
 <td colspan="7" style="padding:10px 0;">
  <hr>
  <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;Tuesday - 02 February 2021</h5>
 </td>
</tr>
```

What I have done is the following:

```
headers = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h5')
results = []

for header in headers:
    result = header.text
    results.append(result)
```

I'd prefer fetching the text from h5 going by the class above this tag, like so:

```
headers = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//tr[@class='dayHeader']/h5")
```

and add it to the mentioned for loop, but I can't seem to get this line to work. How can I do this?

Comment: If you only want `h5` elements within `tr` elements with the class `dayHeader`, then you can use `//tr[@class='dayHeader']/descendant::h5`.

Comment: what is tthe issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. `/` in [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) indicates first child. But the `<h5>` isn't the first child of `//tr[@class='dayHeader']`.

---

### Solution

You need to replace the single forward slash i.e. `/` with a double forward slash i.e. `//` which will indicate a descendant. So your effective line of code will be:

```
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='dayHeader']//h5")])
```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='dayHeader']//h5")))])
```

Comment: Excellent. thanks for your detailed response, it's super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```py
headers = [h.text for h in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//tr[@class='dayHeader']/td/h5")]
```

This is a one-liner for extracting elements and extracting text values to a list.